# Read csv directly from url in html using js

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on html & js in which i display yahoo finance stock in table format. The data get in csv. I want js directly read data from url

The url is http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=RIL.BO

The code i try which i get from stackoverflow is working in localhost url.

```
 var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=RIL.BO", true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
        if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
          allText = txtFile.responseText;
          lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
          alert(allText);
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: some browser not allow cross domain ajax call.  use `jsonp` instead of it

Comment: Gurjinder: Can you upvote or accept any of the answers that were helpful?

Answer (score 6):

In order to get around the Cross Domain request restrictions put in place by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you need an endpoint that allows you to do a JSONP request or that has enabled CORS. Unfortunately, the Yahoo! Finance endpoint has neither.

So, as James mentioned, you ned a middle man.

Usually, my recommendation for this is to use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), which allows you to quickly and easily build a server that sits between you and the finance site. In fact, they already have a Yahoo! Finance endpoint for exactly the data you're trying to get: [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20=%20%22YHOO%22%20and%20startDate%20=%20%222009-09-11%22%20and%20endDate%20=%20%222010-03-10%22&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env)

However, as that can be unreliable, I also have a website scraper that I've used in various projects. It's hosted on Heroku and allows you to fetch almost any content from any site. I don't recommend using it for high volume projects, but for occaisional data fetches it's great. In your case, you would use it like this:

http://websitescraper.herokuapp.com/?url=http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=RIL.BO&callback=jsCallback

*Edit: ichart.finance.yahoo.com has been deprecated, so this fails. Keeping it here for reference*

Now that you have that out of the way, I recommend using jQuery and the [csv-to-array plugin](https://code.google.com/p/csv-to-array/):

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://websitescraper.herokuapp.com/?url=http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=RIL.BO&callback=?', function (csvdata) {
  console.log(csvdata.csvToArray());
});
```

Also, if you want to launch your own middle man, you can use the website-scraper that I've built. The [source code is on GitHub](https://github.com/jhubert/website-scraper) and it's released under the MIT license.

Comment: Checked out the code; nice simple scraper that would be good for Gurjinder to get started with.

Comment: Your website scraper's certificate is expired :(

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers Thanks Erwin. Looks like heroku has dropped support for apps being hosted at heroku.com. I've updated the link to be websitescraper.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do a cross domain request so its being blocked.

You will need to write a server side script to fetch the data for you.